# Selenium getting link from an element on page

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, selenium-chromedriver

In my program i am able to find the element and click it, so I know I have the correct element but when trying to get the link text it returns `Promise { <pending> }` instead of the link, i am using this code as of now

```
target = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin"))).getText();
```

it is also a hyperlink in an email if that helps

Comment: You need to get the link or the text?

Comment: i need to get the link!

Answer (score 2):

```
target = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin"))).getAttribute("src");
```

Try this:

Comment: Shouldn't this be `.getAttribute("href")`?

Comment: Its based on our HTML tag value...We can use href if our HTML tag containing href and viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a the async js selenium webdriver you have to wait until text is available. Will look like:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin"))).then(function() {
    //... Element is Available in DOM

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin")).getAttribute("href").then(function(resolvedLink) {
        //Here the Link is available in Webdriver-Client
         console.log("Link HREF: "+resolvedLink);
    });

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin")).getText().then(function(resolvedText) {
        //Here the Text is available in Webdriver-Client
         console.log("Link Text: "+resolvedText);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but it is return a null value for the text i need the actualy link

Comment: Se my Edit with the href attribute or the getText()

Comment: Thank you powerpete, your .getText(); worked wonders. It got the text of the link for me to later to be split, Thanks you for your help.